# How to Creating a New File Context Menu for Blank (No Extension) File or your own Custom File Extension

Tags: registry, file-extension

I've been looking for a way to create files from the **`Right-Click`** > `New` Menu without an extension. The simple way has always been to create a new Text Document, ***Select All***, & Rename it. but that makes it give you a confirmation dialog & adds an  extra step. As I do this quite often that is a great inconvenience.

I have found 2 questions that seem to be asking a similar thing, but as marked as `Closed` without actually answering the question.

- [How to create my own file extension like .odt or .doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412942/how-to-create-my-own-file-extension-like-odt-or-doc)
- [creating own file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740431/creating-own-file-extension)

So I have pieced together a working method & I wanted to share it, but those questions can no longer be answered.
So I will provide my answer with the question: "Is there a better way to do this?" as that can be answered if there's not a better way, or at the very least the information I have pieced together can be found by others looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

### My Method

So to start we need to create a new extension. This is as easy as creating a New Text Document or editing a file you already have & changing the extension to something. For my use `New Text File.blank` was mine.

This alone won't add it to the Registry. To do this we need to click on the file & assign a program to open it. You must select `Always Use This App to Open...` for it to be added to the Registry. I use Notepad for this purpose, but anything is fine & it should not stick around after you are finished if you use the REG file.

Once we have done this there will be an entry in the registry for the extension

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank`

Now we just have to edit the registry to add this to the context menu &, if you so desire, allow it to create the new file without an extension.

Here's a REG file I edited to do this for me. You can create a New text file with something like `add_new_blank_file.reg`, so long as it ends in '.reg', & paste this code there.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: LostOnTheLine
; Created on: 2023-9-12
; Updated on: 2023-10-2


; Blank Document
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank\ShellNew]

"NullFile"=""


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank]
@="blankfile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

; This line makes it so that when the new file is created it does not have an extension
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank\ShellNew\Config]
"NoExtension"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.blank]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.blank]
"PerceivedType"="document"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\blankfile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\blankfile]
@="Blank File"
"EditFlags"=dword:00210000


[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.blank]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.blank\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.blank\OpenWithProgids]
"blankfile"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.blank\UserChoice]
"Hash"="hyXk/CpboWw="
"ProgId"="blankfile"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.blank]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.blank\UserChoice]
"Hash"="FvJcqeZpmOE="
"ProgId"="blankfile"
```

Now there's almost certainly things in there that aren't needed, like the EditFlags & ProgID, but I took this from a file designed to re-add the `New Text Document` entry if it was lost. As a new text document is 0kb file I just removed the things that I knew to be unnecessary & leave the rest. One addition I did that I did not include here was changing the default Icon for the `.blank` files. it can be done by adding this to the REG file

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\blankfile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Outline.ico"
```

Using your own ICO or DLL file or using one already built-in to windows however you see fit. But it will **only** show on files *with the extension added*, ***not*** the `NoExtension` files created by the Context Menu

This same method can be used without the `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank\ShellNew\Config] "NoExtension"=""` to make it create a new file with `.blank` from the context Menu.

If you would like the extension to be `.myfeet` you could replace every instance of `.blank` with `.myfeet`

Remove this from the REG file (`.blank` replaced with whatever extension you are using)

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.blank\ShellNew\Config]
"NoExtension"=""
```

If you want your file to be called `Feet Maps` replace every instance of `blankfile` with a ProgID you like but this I believe must have no spaces so something like `feetmaps`. Then replace

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\blankfile]
@="Blank File"
```

with

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\feetmaps]
@="Feet Maps"
```

Now when you create a new file in the context menu it will be called `New Feet Maps.myfeet`

---

### Sources

- https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24412-add-remove-default-new-context-menu-items-windows-10-a.html

  - Used as a base for my "*.reg" file